# Can commons-exec executor spawn sub-threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, ant, apache-commons-exec

I have an ant build which compiles C++ using VS cl.exe, groovy and java. I'm building a program to automate switching branches and I've found commons-exec.

The problem I have is that some of the subants spawn multiple threads to speed up the build but the impression I'm getting is that by executing my tasks via commons-exec I'm restricting the entire build to one thread.

Is this the case and is there any way to overcome it (to allow executor subprocesses to spawn threads)

Comment: you can check the documentation, about fork. If is possible with that will be

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any mention of it in the documentation, however it seems to just be javadoc for the most part which is why I asked here, it may be implied by an implemented interface or parent class that I am unfamiliar with

Comment: I'm still seeing slow builds here. My execution process is commons exec - >batch file - ant -> groovy & c & java. Is there any way to invoke the batch file and to allow it the same freedom to spawn threads as if I had typed it on the cmd line without re-writing the build file to use fork()?